# Does [xx:xx] really tell me where the error is located? (Google Big Query)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I got this error message in Google Big Query:
No matching signature for operator = for argument types: INT64, STRING. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [16:7]

I have two questions:
Does the square bracket with "[16:7]" really tells me in which line the error is located?
Looking at the line 16 its empty.

And what kind of problem do I have here?  The leftjoin I'm using are both string and thus same Datatype.

Thank you in advance.
Best

Comment: I find that BigQuery error messages are usually quite accurate.  It might ignore empty lines or something when calculating the error line, but I don't recall such an issue.  The error message itself is pretty clear; what don't you understand about it?

Comment: Hi, can you tell me if 16 is the line and if so , what is the meaning of 7?  [16:7]. And talking about the error message: As I said both numbers are formatted as strings, so I don't understand where the problems lies, if I understood the error message correctly that the datatype is the problem.

Comment: . . It is the character position in the line.  Usually the line is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that BigQuery is quite accurate on the position of  compile-time errors -- including for this error.

The one caveat is if you highlight a query and then run it.  Then the row number is the row number only within the highlighted query -- and this could easily differ from the row number within the window.

As for the error itself, it is a type conflict.  For instance, this triggers the error:

```
select 1 = 'a'
```

If the error is not obvious, you probably have an issue in your data model -- columns in different tables that should have the same type but do not.

To fix it, either convert the integer to a string:

```
cast(1 as string) = 'a'
```

Or safely convert the string to an integer:

```
1 = safe_cast('a' as int64)
```